# Attribute android:requireDeviceUnlock does not perform its function

Tags: android, hce

It's my file apduservice.xml in HCE application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
    <aid-group android:category="other">
        <aid-filter android:name="00000000000401"/>
    </aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>
```

I also tried to change attribute android:requireDeviceUnlock in this file as follows:

```
android:requireDeviceUnlock="true"
```

and tried to run the application without this attribute

```
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <aid-group android:category="other">
            <aid-filter android:name="F0405400400337"/>
        </aid-group>
    </host-apdu-service>
```

but nothing changed. My application works only when display is unlocked, and when display goes out no command comes to my processCommandApdu method.

From the documentation:

> The requireDeviceUnlock attribute can be used to specify that the
>   device must be unlocked before this service can be invoked to handle
>   APDUs.
>
> HCE services can function from the lock-screen however: this is
>   controlled by the android:requireDeviceUnlock attribute in the
>    tag of your HCE service. By default, device unlock
>   is not required, and your service will be invoked even if the device
>   is locked.
>
> If you set the android:requireDeviceUnlock attribute to "true" for
>   your HCE service, Android will prompt the user to unlock the device
>   when you tap an NFC reader that selects an AID that is resolved to
>   your service. After unlocking, Android will show a dialog prompting
>   the user to tap again to complete the transaction. This is necessary
>   because the user may have moved the device away from the NFC reader in
>   order to unlock it.

What am I doing wrong? Help me please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android HCE-Service does only work if your screen is actually on.

[From the HostApduService Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/HostApduService.html):

> Current Android implementations turn the NFC controller and the application processor off completely when the screen of the device is turned off. HCE services will therefore not work when the screen is off.
>   HCE services can function from the lock-screen however: this is controlled by the android:requireDeviceUnlock attribute in the  tag of your HCE service. By default, device unlock is not required, and your service will be invoked even if the device is locked.

The android:requireDevice attribute only asks for the lockscreen if the screen is **on** and your ApduService receives a command. Additionally the user must have set a lockscreen.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to understand this situation.